# Classic error, NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

Classic problem, NoClassDefFoundError what do I need? create new class?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.xsocket.*;
import org.xsocket.connection.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SocketClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            IBlockingConnection bc = new BlockingConnection("127.0.0.1", 8090);
            String req = "Hello server";
            bc.write(req + "\r\n");
        } catch (IOException e){}
            System.out.println("missing");
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
C:\Users\Wildfire\Desktop>java -cp xSocket-2.8.14.jar SocketClient
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SocketClient
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SocketClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: SocketClient.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: What class can't it find? Post the exception trace.

Comment: Are you using notepad/vi? A proper IDE should only import relevant classes not `*`. Check that your imports cover all classes that you are trying to use. (except standard ones like String)

Comment: Add my error message to the post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097944/class-not-found)

Comment: When editing, please be careful to not remove useful information from the question.  @Erick: I merged that questions into this one since this one was more recently updated.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
java -cp xSocket-2.8.14.jar;. SocketClient
```

You are missing the current directory from the class path.

For completeness (thanks to Mark):

on Unix/Linux/etc...:

```
java -cp xSocket-2.8.14.jar:. SocketClient
```

Comment: This.  When you don't specify a classpath, the classpath is the current directory (".").  When you do specify a classpath, the default isn't used so if you want the current directory on the classpath you have to add it explicitly.

Comment: @user217582: see my comment.  The `;` is a path separator (separates two different paths, and on *nix platforms is `:`) and the `.` denotes the current directory.

Comment: Mark added a good clarification for that.  As soon as you redefine the classpath, it must include _everything_ you want, including the current directory.

Comment: Yeah, this work. Thank Mark for the *nix tip too, it is also related to my project.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
java -cp xSocket-2.8.14.jar SocketClient
```

("cp" is short for "classpath")

Comment: @user217582: for which class? SocketClient? If so, have you compiled it?

Comment: it is a class problem, not jar actually

Answer (score 1):

Your classpath is probably wrong. Try:

```
java -classpath dir_missing_from_class_path your_java_file
```

Comment: I don't understand, your question explicitly states that you are experiencing a NoClassDefFoundError error, which my anser is specifically meant to help you with.

Comment: http://jroller.com/sjivan/entry/difference_between_classnotfoundexception_and_noclassdeffounderror