# Can compile but not run the code

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Classic error, NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098787/classic-error-noclassdeffounderror)

The previous question was a mistake which I use javac not java, I was able to compile but cannot run the code

...>java -cp xSocket-2.8.14.jar SocketClient

produce

```
import org.xsocket.connection.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SocketClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        try {
            IBlockingConnection bc = new BlockingConnection("127.0.0.1", 8090);
            String req = "Hello server";
            bc.write(req + "\r\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        System.out.println("missing");
    }
}

C:\Users\Wildfire\Desktop>java -cp xSocket-2.8.14.jar SocketClient.java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SocketClient/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SocketClient.java
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: SocketClient.java.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098787/classic-error-noclassdeffounderror

Comment: My Ecilipse IDE would throw the same exception

Comment: Yes, RD, the java command would still give me the same error.

Comment: You need to leave the ".java" off the class name when you call the java command.

Comment: Is that how you format your code?

Comment: You didn't copy the answer from the previous question carefully :)  Also, you could have added more comments to the previous question instead.

Comment: this is elementary stuff. please read a java book or the sun java tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: But I thought everyone have left for another questions. So I correct my post, I did not use .java which I add in by mistake, I suspect is that the "new Class" is need?

Comment: @user217582: this is **the third** identical question you’re asking. You know, that’s really rude.

Comment: First of all, nobody testing out and point that they are correct. So who is right? Please get xSocket and try it out and you know the answer.

Comment: xSocket has nothing to do with whether java can find the class 'SocketClient'.  The answers you need are in your three questions :)  I promise!

Comment: argh, working too stress, I found the answer. Thanks a lot man. It was already solve and shouldn't have post this question.

Answer (score 8):

You run the class file without the extension, not the java file.

```
java -cp xSocket-2.8.14.jar SocketClient
```

Answer (score -1):

You should specify the Fully Qualified Name of the Class you want to execute. So the correct command should be:

```
java -cp xSocket-2.8.14.jar SocketClient
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same answer as @Martin. If you don't add anything new it is just noise.

Comment: Have you compiled the class? where is the compiled class in your file system? Make sure you run the command from the same directory where the compiled class is.

Comment: I have the xSocket in jar with the SocketClient class on my desktop, when I use the "java -cp xSocket-2.8.14.jar SocketClient", there an error

Comment: try this: java -cp .;xSocket-2.8.14.jar SocketClient